# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named"?

Tags: python

I can't import my own file on my python script

```
import dalto.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'dalto.py\'; \'dalto\' is not a package'
```

They are in the same directory.

I'm using pyCharm, i tried to add the directory to the module path in the settings but it didn't helped.

```
from PIL import Image
import cgitb
import cgi
import dalto.py
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
trad = form.getvalue("value")
if trad == "protanopie":
    suppression_couleur("../img/image.jpg","protanopie")
elif trad == "deuteranopie":
    suppression_couleur("../img/image.jpg", "deuteranopie")
```

Comment: Try just `import dalto`

Comment: Files are an implementation detail. The module is named `dalto`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to write `import dalto`, you must not put the extension at the end of the import file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to read: `import dalto`

Also, if working with Python 3.2 or less, please be sure to include the necessary `__init__.py` files if you're working with your own packages.

Comment: [Since Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) there hasn't been a requirement for `__init__.py` to identify packages.

Comment: @PeterWood, noted, thank you. I updated the answer.